# Is Windows %ERRORLEVEL% == $? in Linux

Tags: batch-file

Trying my hands on windows batch files, in the below code that I found by searching in www.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Call this with two arguments, and it will add them.
SET a=%1+%2
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (goto errors-0) ELSE (goto errors-1)
REM Instead of using goto with the variable, this uses an IF-ELSE structure
:errors-0
REM This is if it was successful
ECHO %a%
goto exit
:errors-1
REM this is if it had an error:
ECHO Errors occurred.
goto exit
REM GUESS WHAT, THIS REM WILL NEVER EVER BE READ!  IT WILL BE SKIPPED OVER BY THE GOTOS
:exit
ECHO.
ECHO press any key to exit.
PAUSE>nul
```

The code is suppose to take 2 arguments, add them and echo the result.

But this won't execute with success on my Windows 8.1 machine. Below is what I get:

```
C:\ProjectDoc>add3.bat
Errors occurred.

press any key to exit.
```

So, U added an echo for the `ERRORLEVEL` to see its value after executing the command `SET`. Below is the output:

```
C:\ProjectDoc>add3.bat 2 3
9009
Errors occurred.

press any key to exit.
C:\ProjectDoc>
```

So, is this `errorlevel` in Windows equal to the `$?` of Linux. Should it be returning 0 for every successful execution of a command or is it different? Reading some docs relates it to the Linux `$?` but it isn't clearly working as `$?` in Linux.

Comment: Turn `Echo on` on first line and you'll see what is happening.

Comment: The question was "is the errorlevel equivalent to $? For unix/linux"? If u understanding what i am asking

Comment: In general yes, `ErrorLevel` is the return code that indicates success by being `0`; however, the problem is that commands use it differently: some set it in case of errors but do not reset it in case of success (e. g., `set`); some do reset it (e. g., `copy`); some use even non-zero numbers for success, to indicate a result (`choice`)...

Comment: Whether it's "equivalent to $? in unix/linux" depends on which shell you are using in unix/linux.

Comment: Read the help for the `SET` command. Also the dos tag is not valid for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to be precise, %errorlevel% is analogous to $? in Bash shell.

In your batch file, `SET a=%1+%2` is not doing what you expect it to do. It just sets the value of the variable `a` to the string "2+3" assuming you ran the file with arguments `2 3`. If you want to do arithmetic you need to use the /A option: `set /a a=%1+%2`.

The SET command (and many other built-in commands) only set the ERRORLEVEL if there has actually been an error. If it was successful, the ERRORLEVEL will retain its previous value. I think this is what you're witnessing in your question.

By contrast, when a command runs an executable file, when the process completes it always sets the ERRORLEVEL.

As well as checking the ERRORLEVEL variable for specific values, it is idiomatic (for historical reasons) to check the errorlevel using the following expression

`IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Hello`

This will run the given command if `ERRORLEVEL` is 1 *or above* - in other words, if any error has occurred.

Comment: Agreed that the command with the syntax: `SET a=%1+%2` is not performing the arithmetic as desired due to the lack of the option `/a`. But the command as such (without the `/a` switch) is not wrong. It set the value to a string `"2+3"`. So in a Linux environment, the `$?` will return 0 for this. But the windows batch sets/retains a value 9009. why is this so?  Although i think, this is what you are trying to say in the 3rd para of your answer? `"The SET command (and many other built-in commands) only set the ERRORLEVEL if there......................"`

Comment: @OK9999 exactly. The error value 9009 must have been left over from some previous operation, and because the SET command succeeded, it didn't change this error value. cmd.exe is full of quirks.